# how to rewire 3 way switch

Tags: electrical

I just moved into this house. There's a 3 way switch that I can't figure out how to rewire it.When I turn it on at the bottom of the stairs, I can turn it off at the top of the stairs. But after doing that it won't be able to turn back on at the bottom of the stairs unless I switch it back on at the top of the stairs. I included a picture of how previous owner wired it, also a picture of all the  wire combinations I tried. 
"Not Work" - lights won't turn on. 
"Worked"- light will turn on but still the same problem. So I hope someone can tell me how to rewire it. Thanks 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tested both switches? the comm should connect to one terminal in one position and the other terminal in the other position.

Comment: T: top switch  B: bottom switch   Isn't the Black wire always suppose to be on the common terminal?

Comment: Use a multimeter.

Comment: How did you identify the common wire? Actually seeing a black screw, or inference based on screw position?  Wire colors are semi-meaningless ..  but very meaningless in 3-ways.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: No I don't have a multimeter. Basically you can say I played musical chairs with the wires. First Idisconnected both switches, then I just rewired one switch to see which wire is the HOT wire.  Then I rewired both of them. The results was both light switch will only turn on when the RED wire is directly across from the BLACK wire.

Comment: The Big Yellow wire in Switch 1, I know for sure that is the wire from the light. So the HOT wire on the common screw should be correct.   I'm guessing this, is the problem lying on the  wire on the right side where the black and red wire is wire nut to the black wire. That wire on the Right side should be the wire for the 2nd switch

Comment: I think it's time to check all other junction boxes that could possibly be related to this circuit, to see what the other end of these /3 cables might be doing.

Answer (score 2):

Several **wires** in a sheath is called a **cable**.  The difference gets important fast.

### Traveler *wires*

First, it's time to stop the dizziness and confusion with the travelers.  You should not have to play musical chairs with travelers.  (It's not hazardous so as long as you are only exchanging the wires which belong on the 3-way, but it's a stupid waste of time).  And to save us trouble later, let's **mark the travelers**; I recommend [yellow tape](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-2-in-x-20-ft-Colored-Electrical-Tape-5-Pack-GTPC-550/100054213), but if that color is already assigned, just use blue.  Mark both travelers the same color, there is no need to distinguish them from each other.

This will always be true about travelers:

- There is no wire-color standard. Really. That's why we mark them!
- Both traveler wires are in the same /3 cable
- Both traveler wires go to the 3-way switch
- In the same /3 cable, travelers stay the same color. We don't have "crossover cables" in mains electrical.
- However if the /3 cable is spliced somewhere, all bets are off.

So. In box 2, all 3 wires go to the switch, so that's no help at all.  However in box 1's left /3 cable, red and white go to the switch.  *Gotcha!*

Red and white get marked yellow (or blue if you prefer).  In switch #1 box, and also switch #2 box, unless you have reason to believe the cable is spliced somewhere else.

### Identifying the common screw terminal

You've talked a lot about screw positions and never about screw colors.  On 3-ways, **screw positions are meaningless. Screw colors matter**.  The common screw is black, the traveler screws are brass/yellow.

Now we've identified the traveler positions by logic, and identified the traveler screws by color.  There is **only one way** this can possibly connect, and **it must work**. Unless:

### A third 3-way (4-way), or splice in a lamp box?

Remember the part where I said "if the /3 cable is spliced in another box, all bets are off"?   That could happen in a lamp box, or the site of a current or former 4-way switch. There's no substitute but to search every possible box for this.  You'll recognize it when 2 wires from a /3 cable are spliced to 2 wires from another /3 cable. (Not counting grounds).

In that case, the traveler principles still apply, but you have to figure out which cable is which amongst several white /3 cables coming into that intermediate box.  *...and this, this is why I advocate marking travelers with colored tape.*

There's one more possibility.  Here, we presume the *left* /3 cable connects to box 2.  What if it's actually the *right* /3 cable??? That would make this whole thing a bodge job of considerable proportion, but it would explain a lot. The troubleshooting here might be beyond you, and it might be time to bring in a handyman.

Comment: I added a clearer picture, you mention splicing.  Box 1 The cable on the right, the black and red wire is that considered spliced?

Comment: @oliveoil10 splicing is any joining of 2 or more wires.  You showed 3 splices in your earlier diagram and four in your latest, since you are showing the red/black tape join as separate from the wire nut.   The tape join is illegal and unsafe, and should be undone and redone with a wire nut.  Tape has no place in splices.  It may hide something that is not a splice, like the capping off and termination of the red wire and merely taping it against the insulated black wire. Tape clumps are illegal *least* because they're hard to inspect. But mainly, they make poor connections.

Comment: I think previous owner taped the wires together because they were too short so that is why another black wire was attached to it then to the wire nut.

Comment: Assuming  switch 1 the connection of the wires is correct, If the cable on the left is connected to switch 2, is the placement of the wires correct?

Comment: @oliveoil10 I cannot possibly say, because I don't know which screws are black and which are brass.  Position means absolutely nothing on 3-ways.  Every make and model of switch randomizes where they put common vs travelers, even two switches of the same SKU may be different.

Comment: I labeled it in the picture. The common screw is on the bottom right.

Comment: ***How do you know that?*** Not to be obtuse, but this whole problem  turns on the proper identification of common, and nothing you have said suggests that you have any idea how to do that.  Even if it's an "of course/obviously" I'd really like to hear it from you, to make sure we are on the same page.  Also, in the "unmentioned" department... are these smart switches, dimmers, anything other than a plain old $1.30 3-way?

Comment: I know that is the Common because the screw is black and when I took out the light switch "common" was written on the back behind  the black screw. Anyways thanks for your help, but  my guess was right, the cable on Right does lead to switch 2, I swapped the wires and now everything is working

Comment: @oliveoil10 thanks, that's the "obviously" I just needed to make sure of, and yeah... That cable on the right *has* been lingering in this story like Chekhov's Gun, I'm not surprised it's the crux of the problem.  The too-short issue is very worrisome. The wires need to come out beyond the wall 3" to be Code.